# Last observation carried forward query (SELECT from-between incomplete time series)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I have a table that gets a new row only when some recalculations are completed (`TOTAL` column)

```
DATE_REFRESH    TOTAL
2020-08-28     40000.00
2020-09-04     60000.00
2020-09-22    100000.00
2020-10-13    125000.00
```

I need to `SELECT` a date `2020-09-15` and return `60 000` which is the last amount before the next update/refresh on `2020-09-22`

Desired result: `60 000`

Ty!

Comment: SQL Server or Oracle? What are you *really* using? What have *you* tried so far? Why didn't it work? A `TOP` (or Oracle equivalent) with a simple `WHERE` would surely do this, so why doesn't that work?

Comment: is TOTAL string column OR decimal because expected output 60 000 OR 60.000?

Comment: I have removed the conflicting tags, please retag the RDBMS you are *really* using and only that RDBMS.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server and the TOTAL column is float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order by` and `top (1)`:

```
select top (1) *
from mytable 
where date_refresh <= '20200915'
order by date_refresh desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understood your problem and my approach was to solve it in SQL was with DATEDIFF().
So the SQL Script would be following:

```
SELECT TOTAL FROM (*your table*)
WHERE DATE_REFRESH = (
 SELECT TOP 1 DATE_REFRESH
 FROM (*your table*)
 WHERE DATE_REFRESH < (*your date*)
 ORDER BY DATEDIFF ( (*your date*), DATE_REFRESH )
)
```

I'm selecting TOTAL from the row where the nearest (`TOP 1 FROM - ORDER BY DATEDIFF()`) smaller (`DATE_REFRESH < (*your date*)`) date to your date is.

I hope it helped. :)